# Unusual behavior of coordinate grid in QGis Composer

Tags: qgis, coordinates, print-composer, grids-graticules

The coordinates in the grid in QGis composer display incorrectly when using the "degrees, minutes, seconds" option (or even decimal degrees). It displays West and East in the longitude and North and South in the latitude (or positive and negative) and sometimes it even mixes UTM and degrees.

[image: QGis showing wrong coordinates in composer]

It doesn't seem to have any problem with decimal format (UTM) as shown below, but no matter what I do it still has the same trouble with degrees.

[image: UTM coordinates showing correctly in QGis Composer]

I have done multiple maps in QGis 2.14 and 2.12 having the same problem and I remember that in earlier versions this did not happen. Is there any way to fix this?

June, 2018: It seems new versions of QGis don't have this problem.

Comment: I've run into a similar problem before when trying to add graticule to my maps. Curious to see an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I've just found out what's going on. You have to switch interval units from "millimeters" or "centimeters" to "units of map". Then the software will use the shp coordinate system to generate the grid.

[image]

Comment: Where do I find that menu?

Answer (score 0):

Try these as shown in the screen shot box below;

Set the 'Interval units' to 'Map unit' and then for 'Interval' (both the X and Y) value, try key in '0.1' or '0.01' or any smaller numeric value until you see the supposedly correct coordinates appear on the map composer. Of course, you may try with other numbers than 1 such as '0.05'. Hope this solves the problem.

[image]